# Find index of an element in list using wildcards

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
a = [['1','2','3','a','b'],
     ['4','5','6','c','d'],
     ['7','8','9','e','f']]
```

I want to identify the index of an element in the list `a` based on first three sub-elements of the element. For example, the index of the element which contains `['4','5','6']` as its first three sub-elements is 1.

I have tried to do this using list comprehension follows:

```
ind = [i for i in range(0,len(a)) if (a[i][0] == '4' and a[i][1] == '5' and a[i][2] == '6')]
```

But this is computationally expensive as I have to implement this code several times in a for loop. So, I am looking for a less computationally expensive method. SO far I have tried 'list.index' as follows:

```
ind = a.index(['4','5','6','*','*'])
```

where `'*'` is used as wildcard string. But is does not work as it outputs:

```
['4', '5', '6', '.*', '.*'] is not in list
```

I think there is something wrong with the way I am using wildcard. Can you please tell me what is it? Or is there another fast way to identify the element of a list based on its sub-elements?

Comment: Your question title implies you must solve this by using wildcards. Is that the case? I don't think that's the easiest way to solve this, but if that's a requirement for some reason, I'm sure it's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Solution 1: True wildcard

You can simply use `a.index(...)` if you use a true wildcard:

```
class Wildcard:
    def __eq__(self, anything):
        return True

a = [['1','2','3','a','b'],
     ['4','5','6','c','d'],
     ['7','8','9','e','f']]

wc = Wildcard()

print(a.index(['4', '5', '6', wc, wc]))
```

Outputs `1`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc5NCsIwEAXg/ZxidkmgCFp/WsFbCC5KCDFJNVBiTVuqp48Ti@DAtxge85j@Pd4foaz6mJLp9DDgxXfW6GiPgDTWtaiUeyrFB9e1BepAFz7cxJLniW6cYsBznByAxhM2DVuzgm1ISTS5MlksBw3b0r4je2KI/csOtFekJo60TEqA2VDr7zEuAProw8j1ygfrXvxbibkTcynOJpNCpPQB)

This might be fast because 1) it does the searching in C code and 2) it does minimal work, as it for example doesn't create a list slice for every row and might often rule out a row simply by looking at just the first value.

---

##### Solution 2: operator.indexOf

Or using `operator.indexOf`, which finds the index in C rather than in Python like an `enumerate` solution would. Here are two versions of that, I suspect the one mapping a ready-to-go `slice` is faster:

```
from operator import indexOf, itemgetter

a = [['1','2','3','a','b'],
     ['4','5','6','c','d'],
     ['7','8','9','e','f']]

print(indexOf((r[:3] for r in a), ['4', '5', '6']))
print(indexOf(map(itemgetter(slice(3)), a), ['4', '5', '6']))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7LCkIhEAbgvU8xOxXclF1OQc/QA4gLO0dLyAuTi3p6m0NBEQnfYhj@8a@PdilZDxV7D1gSlOrRtYIQUy3YIObJ349BQWw@nX1rHhlzcABj@IIrviSaOHLiVjGYn@ErmtdkQ0Yyfe22NA9kRzwJ3FrGKsbcxPs/IdDstYVATahLBifV6yrMZ4HuWil/MslV8akpbtc4eqElJf@me38C)

Comment: The `Wildcard` class solution is great :) It is actually highly extensible as if we have a requirement that instead of any character, let's say what we need to match instead is any digit but not letters, we can simply extend that class and implement `__eq__` with `return anything.isdigit()`, endless possible extensions. Also isn't fixed to only the start of the list. +1 :)

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano Or instead of hardcoding, make it [configurable](https://tio.run/##dZDLCsMgEEX3foU7DYRA32mh39FFCGGqhgjWWrWvr0/HpinpogNnMTP33hHdM3Znuyid73thIAR60EYK8HJHKJZULW0abXVsGh6UaXN6gig6FbJBkCrNi8@Y7kfBxK8uX/cNzFVNvF7Fq7c/EXzQEAIYVlVsxnI2RxYIIEdW54O/YkvsV8gaEW/N/52c7DbYl8gWUUjL6pqQu8CL4wfwEH2hAxjXAT7GeW0jh0JbqR78nU5TPE359C4SdZb1/Qs).

Comment: That is even better :)

Comment: I tried the wildcard method. It is about 20 time faster than the list comprehension method. Thanks.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta What about the two `indexOf` solutions? Could be faster, could be slower, depending on your data.

Comment: Let me try indexOf method too.

Comment: Actually I think the indexOf solutions will be slower, for the reason I just added under the wildcard solution. At least if your wildcards are, like in your example, at the end.

Comment: The wildcard solution is perfect as long as the sizes of the sub-lists are fixed, which is indeed the case for the OP. +1

Comment: @blhsing Yeah, I think they wouldn't have tried their own wildcard attempt if they had different lengths.

Comment: Yeah, the indeoxOf method is slower than wildcard method. But it is faster than the list comprehension method I used. For the code that I have following were the approximate times taken by the three methods:
List comprehension: 140 secs, indexOf: 107 secs; Wildcard: 7 secs

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Good, thanks. Bit disappointing about indexOf, but then again, your own method already had part of the advantage of my wildcard solution: you're not slicing for every row but might rule out most rows already with your single `a[i][0] == '4'` check.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could transpose and slice and transpose back and finally index, like this:

```
>>> list(zip(*list(zip(*a))[:3])).index(('4', '5', '6'))
1
>>>
```

But what's wrong with?

```
>>> [x[:3] for x in a].index(['4', '5', '6'])
1
>>>
```

Comment: Let me try the second approach first and see if it reduces the computation time.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Cool!

Comment: I tried both of your solutions. But they were not more efficient than list comprehension method . But thanks a lot.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Yes, for length, mine would be the way to go, but for efficiency the 0ther answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more efficient to implement it as a generator. In this way, if e.g. you know that you can get at most one match you can stop once it is found:

```
a = [['1','2','3','a','b'],
     ['4','5','6','c','d'],
     ['7','8','9','e','f']]


pattern = ['4','5','6']

def find_index(data, pattern):
    for n, elt in enumerate(a):
        if elt[:3] == pattern:
            yield n

indices = find_index(a, pattern)
next(indices)
```

It gives:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple and straightforward way of accomplishing this:

```
def findListMatch(lists, match):
    # Loop over lists with indices
    for k, sublist in enumerate(lists):
        # Check if the beginning of the list matches the desired start pattern
        if sublist[0:len(match)] == match:
            # If it's a match, return the index
            return k
    # If none of the lists match, return a placeholder value of "None"
    return None

a = [['1','2','3','a','b'],
     ['4','5','6','c','d'],
     ['7','8','9','e','f']]

matchIndex = findListMatch(a, ['4', '5', '6'])

# Result:
# matchIndex = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

@U12-Forward's answer works but unnecessarily builds a temporary list of the same size as the input list before applying the `index` method, which can be quite an overhead if the list is long. A more efficient approach would be to use `enumerate` to generate the indices while comparing the first 3 items to the desired list:

```
next(i for i, l in enumerate(a) if l[:3] == ['4', '5', '6'])
```