# Is there any way to make an element in a list equal all integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get these two list to equal one another:

```
a = [None, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, None, 0, -3, 2, None, None, None]
b = [0, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 0, 0, -3, 2, 0, 0, 0]
if a == b:
    print("yay or sth")
```

Currently I have `None` as a placeholder.
other than using a for loop and checking every single one, is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Interesting question. `NaN` is defined to be *not* equal to every other value (including itself), so you might want to look into that.

Comment: You can define a separate class whose `__eq__` method always returns true, but that's not true equality. Equality implies transitivity: if `a == b` and `b == c`, then `a == c`. But your special placeholder would violate that: with `a = Special()`, then `1 == a == 3` is true but `1 != 3`.

Comment: @chepner the placehoder _None_ is just there so the list looks a bit more clearer. in this case 'None' can be switched out for anything else.

Comment: And anything else would have the problem I mentioned. You don't want a value that's equal to any integer: you want a list-comparison function that returns true iff all corresponding non-placeholder values are equal. Save `==` for actual equality.

Comment: What exactly is the intended usage? Do you want to specify a "pattern" list `a` with such placeholders, and then have "data" lists `b` with just numbers, and you want to check whether the data lists match the pattern list?

Comment: @KellyBundy I want to check if everything in "pattern" list (with the placeholders always returning `True` no matter what thing the same index in data list has) is the same as the "data" list

Comment: Ok so the data list doesn't have such placeholders, right? And do you use the same pattern list for multiple data lists?

Comment: No the data list doesn't have placeholders. And no there are only two lists and they are a and b.

Comment: Would be clearer to give meaningful and distinguishing names then, e.g., `pattern` and `data`. @chepner's answer could then also be optimized to not check for `None` in `b`/`data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) noted in the comments, you could create a class with a `__eq__` method that always returns `True`. Then you could create a global variable with an instance of the class and use, like this:

```
class EqualClass():
    def __eq__(self, obj):
        return True


Equal = EqualClass()

a = [Equal, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, Equal, 0, -3, 2, Equal, Equal, Equal]
b = [0, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 0, 0, -3, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Or, as [Kelly Bundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy) pointed out in a comment, you can use [`unittest.mock.ANY`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any) ([source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/88a1e6db0ff7856191a5d63d3d26a896f3ae5885/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L2416-L2428)). Like this:

```
from unittest.mock import ANY

a = [ANY, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, ANY, 0, -3, 2, ANY, ANY, ANY]
b = [0, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 0, 0, -3, 2, 0, 0, 0]
print(a == b)  # => True
```

However, be sure to see [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75270940/13376511) regarding transitivity and why this may be a bad idea.

Comment: For example, `c = [0]*13`. `a == b` and `a == c`, but `b != c`.

Comment: @chepner `a == c` is wrong.

Comment: Ugh, got too lazy. `c = list(b); c[0] = 1`.

Comment: @Michael [Already exists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any), btw ([source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/88a1e6db0ff7856191a5d63d3d26a896f3ae5885/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L2416-L2428)).

Comment: Hmm, why that generator instead of `a == b`?

Comment: @KellyBundy Ah, another good catch. For some reason, I thought they wouldn't be equal (must have gotten confused with another language).

Comment: Also note my new comment under chepner's answer.

Answer (score 3):

`==` is supposed to be transitive: if `a == b` and `b == c`, then `a == c`. But such a placeholder would violate that.

Better to simplify define another function to make the comparison you want instead of making `__eq__` do something it should not.

```
def basically_equal(l1, l2):
    return all(x is None or y is None or x == y for x, y in zip(l1, l2))

if basically_equal(a, b):
    print("a and b equal up to placeholder values")
```

Comment: I'd say it depends on how it's used. If that placeholder is for example defined and used only *inside* a function to implement that function's functionality, then I see nothing wrong with it. And it has a performance advantage. See for example [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69217591/12671057) being much faster than other alternatives at the task of finding a matching list (the OP there said "about 20 time faster than the list comprehension method", though I'm not quite sure what list comp and what data they used).

Comment: @chepner The elements that correspond to the placeholders in "b" list I don't care about what they are, because the placeholders are just leftovers from when I created a list having no way of knowing how many elements are going to be in there and where, and so have no use for. So I did `a = [None]*999`.

Comment: Might be nicer (and would be faster) to do the None-check(s) in an if-clause instead: [code](https://tio.run/##ZY9dCsIwEITfc4rBpxZWqFZBhV7BC4jItk0xEJKYptJ6@dofRdF9WHZm9oNd14WrNenO@b4vZYWca1Ww1t1F3hrWkV4R9Do@CAzlZWi8wRBHLbIM3eR@VWU9WkIHZfBQ7k3/rqkKLVQNYwOO1kiwKUfo48RCMDKcxpmQEjaELWFH2BNmMyEsh2D91p9@FvnIJn9g8k3NIjkLof7fZkL@etp5ZUK04OnIHFOOxiFYOM2FvFpdSo8760bWi7jvnw)

Comment: The term "equality" has meaning, and I don't recommend changing that just because someone likes the `==` syntax for something different. I'm also not interested in bike-shedding the approach just to optimize the performance.