# Python remove row from list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that looks like this in Python...

```
[
    ["item 1",  'green', 'round',     'sold'],
    ["item73",  'red',   'square',    'for sale'],
    ['item477', 'blue',  'rectangle', 'on hold']
]
```

I have the name of the item `item73` generated by another process. How can I delete the matching list from this list of lists so I end up with..

```
[
    ["item 1",  'green', 'round',     'sold'],
    ['item477', 'blue',  'rectangle', 'on hold']
]
```

It seems like a simple task but I am stuck unable to do it. I have tried...

```
mylist.remove('item73')
```

But this is not working

Comment: First find the row it's in. Then delete that row? You forgot the first part in the code attempt you're showing. The code you're showing tries to delete the single string `"item73"`, and `mylist` doesn't contain strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest option IMO is to build a new list in a comprehension, since that makes it really easy to filter out the unwanted row:

```
>>> mylist = [
...     ["item 1",  'green', 'round',     'sold'],
...     ["item73",  'red',   'square',    'for sale'],
...     ['item477', 'blue',  'rectangle', 'on hold']
... ]
>>> mylist = [i for i in my_list if 'item73' not in i]
>>> mylist
[['item 1', 'green', 'round', 'sold'], ['item477', 'blue', 'rectangle', 'on hold']]
```

You can do it with `remove`, though, by first constructing an expression that will return the desired row (you need the *entire* row for `remove` to know what it's removing, not just part of it):

```
>>> mylist.remove(next(i for i in mylist if 'item73' in i))
>>> mylist
[['item 1', 'green', 'round', 'sold'], ['item477', 'blue', 'rectangle', 'on hold']]
```

One drawback of this approach is that it only works if there's exactly one matching row, whereas the list comprehension approach can easily remove multiple rows that match a given condition.

Comment: Though `mylist.remove([i for i in mylist if ....][0])` wouldn't really be much more complex. Hah, never mind, you added that as I left the comment.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Or simply `mylist.remove(['item73', ANY, ANY, ANY])` ([demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZA9bsMwDIV3nYLIwgRwAxQJ4CwZeoHuReDBTehEiCS6FFUgZ-mSpb1TT9K1spU_DgQJfI985NdPf9IDh_P5O2n3tPr964Q9pGBVKerc8_YI1vcsCi-vb8b4k7NRYQ0bAzk2E6vk4XlSAeBeiAJWgMIp7HIxBEZ2O2yqB7xejLhQYTB-pFao8NixQGwd3SQ4SJZ1PQx-d2nksnarbdi7oUMOcBiXmOZqcC7k-ZOmRV0vMpbt31MzM6YXG3Ra-Fk5__KF6zf-AQ)).

Comment: Oh, nice! Literally never seen that before.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Probably also fast, just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69217591/12671057).

Comment: That's pretty amazing.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the item number is always the first element in the sublists, and you only need to delete one sublist, then there is a straightforward way:

```py
for i, row in enumerate(mylist):
    if row[0] == 'item73':
        mylist.pop(i)
        break
```